# Why do we use div sometimes and sometimes not?

Tags: html, class, ids

Why is div written before an id in the first example? (please look below) and not written before class="my-form"> in the second example (please look below)? sometimes we use div and sometimes not. Can you give me the reason?

First example:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p> 
    
</div>
```

Second example:

```
    <form class="my-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name: </label>
            <Input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Email </label>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="">
    </form>
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. The code you've posted doesn't have any IDs at all

Comment: My question is when do we use a div before and after classes and when we don't? <form class="my-form"> 
        why didn't the teacher write a div before the class here?

Comment: @HibaHammami Your question doesn't make much sense. Div's and form's are elements while classes and id's are attributes that belong to elements.

Comment: I know. I'm new to coding with markup languages,HTML and CSS. Could you please read my question again and try to understand it? When do we write divs before giving classes and when we just give a class without using divs? I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check it.

Comment: Hi @HibaHammami - unfortunately, we still do not understand what you are trying to ask here. Order of *attributes* does not matter, and `div` is part of the tag name, which *always* comes first, this is the HTML syntax...

Answer (score 1):

You are writing HTML here.

In HTML you use tags to declare the elements of your document.

When you want to specify a first-order heading u can use the tag `h1` like so:

```html
<h1>My Headline</h1>
```

And that will be rendered as a heading by your browser.

***So what about that `div`?***

A `div` is just another html element, that describes a block on your page.
You can use divs for grouping and structuring other elements.

***What about `class`?***

In HTML you can use attributes to declare additional properties for your elements. One of those attributes is the `class`-attribute. It is used to tell your browser, which CSS-class(es) to use for styling an element.

Here I made up a css-class with the name "red-color" that assigns red color to its elements. In the html-code I use the `class`-attribute to use that style-class for the second heading.

```css
.red-color {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Default style heading</h1>
<h1 class="red-color">Custom style-class heading</h1>
```

You never use any attribute without an element (tag).

***What about the intensions of your instructor?***

Nobody knows, but you can ask your instructor.